# Find the intersection points of the line L with the three coordinate planes Oxy, Oyz, and Ozx

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let $L$ be the line given by the parametric equations
$x = 1 + 2t, y = −1 − t, z = 3t$

Find the intersection points of the line $L$ with the three coordinate planes $O_{xy}, O_{yz}, O_{zx}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For example, for the $x$-$z$ plane, you want $y=0$, so $-1-t=0$, meaning that  $t=-1$. Substitute. We get $(-1,0,-3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the intersecting point to be $(x,y,z)$

1. Intersecting $O_{xy}$ implies $z=0$. Substitute $z=0$ into $L$'s parametric form, obtaining $t=0$, hence $x=1,y=-1$
2. Intersecting $O_{yz}$ implies $x=0$. Substitute $x=0$ into $L$'s parametric form, obtaining $t=-1/2$, hence $y=-1/2,z=-3/2$
3. Intersecting $O_{xz}$ implies $y=0$. Substitute $y=0$ into $L$'s parametric form, obtaining $t=-1$, hence $x=-1,z=-3$

**Check** You may use geometry to verify the answer.
[image]